# how do i solve the deprecation warning while compiling

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

what does this warning mean and how to resolve it. Is it something I should worry about. I've tried reading the webpack's documentation.

[image: Compilation warning message]

Comment: Please add the warning text to the question rather than using a screenshot/image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to worry about deprecation warnings, from time to time some or the other library will adapt to something new and deprecate the previous (it will work fine though) for various reasons like security loopholes, performance or something better. Your warning appears to be related to html-webpack-plugin

In your webpack.config add the stats property like below to suppress warnings

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  stats: { warnings:false }
}
```

Also, try uninstalling your html-webpack-plugin and install latest || upgrade to fix it

`node --trace-deprecation ./node_modules/.bin/the_library_name_here` will list all deprecations

You could do `npm outdated` to check the latest versions. or simply `npm update --force` as well to update.