# Webpack: Suppressing warnings from a specific file

Tags: javascript, webpack, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, webpack-5

I'm trying to suppress some FontAwesome Sass compilation warnings that obviously cannot be fixed from my end like so:

```
config.ignoreWarnings = [
  {
    file: /_bootstrap\.scss$/i
  }
]
```

But the warnings are not ignored or suppressed. Maybe `ignoreWarnings` does not suppress compilation warnings? Regardless, how can warnings generated from compiling this Sass file be ignored?

**Generated Warnings**

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(20em, 16)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
12 │ $fa-fw-width:          (20em / 16);
   │                         ^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\scss\_variables.scss 12:25  @import
    node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\scss\fontawesome.scss 5:9   @import
    assets\styles\_bootstrap.scss 4:9                                      @import
    assets\styles\app.scss 1:9                                             root stylesheet

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(4em, 3)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

  ╷
6 │   font-size: (4em / 3);
  │               ^^^^^^^
  ╵
    node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\scss\_larger.scss 6:15     @import
    node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\scss\fontawesome.scss 8:9  @import
    assets\styles\_bootstrap.scss 4:9                                     @import
    assets\styles\app.scss 1:9                                            root stylesheet

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(3em, 4)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

  ╷
7 │   line-height: (3em / 4);
  │                 ^^^^^^^
  ╵
    node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\scss\_larger.scss 7:17     @import
    node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\scss\fontawesome.scss 8:9  @import
    assets\styles\_bootstrap.scss 4:9                                     @import
    assets\styles\app.scss 1:9                                            root stylesheet

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($fa-li-width * 5, 4)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

  ╷
6 │   margin-left: $fa-li-width * 5/4;
  │                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
    node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\scss\_list.scss 6:16        @import
    node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\scss\fontawesome.scss 10:9  @import
    assets\styles\_bootstrap.scss 4:9                                      @import
    assets\styles\app.scss 1:9                                             root stylesheet

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 7725ms
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do i solve the deprecation warning while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68208552/how-do-i-solve-the-deprecation-warning-while-compiling)

Comment: @deechris27 No, it does not. I don't want to suppress all warnings, just the warnings from this file.

Comment: @deechris27 I've also tested that method to see if the warnings would be silenced and they were not.

Answer (score 2):

In my case using `file regex` didn't work, I fixed it using `module regex` instead

**Not working**

```
ignoreWarnings: [
    {
        file: /path\/to\/file\/style.scss$/,
        message: /the warning/,
    },
],
```

**Working**

```
ignoreWarnings: [
    {
        module: /path\/to\/file\/style.scss$/,
        message: /the warning/,
    },
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

```
ignoreWarnings: [
      {
        file: /file_name/,
        message: /your warning message that need to be suppressed/,
      },
      (warning, compilation) => true
    ]
```

Ref: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Comment: That doesn't work atm. I've added the warnings I'm trying to ignore into the original post, and am currently implementing your recommendation like so: `config.ignoreWarnings = [{ file: /_bootstrap.scss$/, message: /^DEPRECATION WARNING/, }, (warning, compilation) => true]`

Comment: Simpler is just give list of regexps, like
`ignoreWarnings: [  /a dependency is an expression/  ],    /* suppress warnings from 3rd party libs */`

Granted, could match unexpected bits...